# CSS background color layered with gradient

Tags: css, background, gradient

Is it possible to set a background color in css, and then layer it with gradient? Like i do in photoshop?

I thought i could do it like:

```
background: #445566, linear-gradient(0deg, blue, green 40%, red);
```

but this obviously doesn't work

Is there some way of achieving it?

Answer (score 0):

yes, like so :

```
background: green linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(125,185,232,0) 100%);
```

note that the first thing after `background` is your color `green`, then followed by the `gradient` from `blue` to `transparent` ( no comma )

you can put the `color` at the end if you want.

```css
#myDiv{
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
   background: green linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(125,185,232,0) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two solution. You can define the gradient as background and then set background-color :

```css
.box {
 height:200px;
 background: linear-gradient(0deg, transparent,red);
 background-color:#445566; /* Should be place after background property*/
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Or

```css
.box {
 height:200px;
 background-color:#445566; /* Can be placed here */
 background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, transparent,red);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

If you check the [documenation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) you can also see that you are able to append the background color as the last value when using multiple background:

[image]

```css
.box {
 height:200px;
 background: linear-gradient(0deg, transparent,red), #445566;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```